# Gherkin: when and then step definition are more or less the same

Tags: bdd, specflow, gherkin

I have the following specification:

*Scenario: **Retrieve customer license document**

    Given I have a customer with no license

    When I retrieve the license document

    Then the license document should not be retrieved*

In this scenario the When and Then step definition are more of less the same. What I want to specify with this scenario is that it's not possible to retrieve a license document when the customer has no license.

*When I Retrieve the license document* implies that the retrieving of the license is possible.

Does anyone have a solution to rewrite this scenario?

Comment: Maybe if you change the wording, it fits what you want. "When I try to retrieve the license document"

Comment: The question a posed now is not so much about programming as about choosing the correct wording.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, the when clause is redundent

> *Scenario: **Retrieve customer license document**
>
>      Given I have a customer with no license
>
>      <strike>When I retrieve the license document</strike>
>
>      Then the license document should not be retrieved*

Put the then caluse's codebehind implemenyation in try catch. In catch, post a success. In try block, at the end raise an exception.

Comment: In my opinion there always has to be an action. So I can't just forget about the When statement...  

Another option:  

Given I have a customer with no license    
When i Try to retrieve the license document  
Then the license document should not be retrieved  

But that doesn't sound right because you just can't 'try' something. That's not an action.

Comment: Gherkin is not about being english gramatically correct. It is about having a test script which is easily understood by BAs and which can double as documentation. Specflow or any other gherkin impl. treats given/when/then as same, in fact they just strip the prefix. So it boils down to do what is simple. You can have all the three statents, catch the exception in When clause and verify the existance of exception in then clause. But why write so much code to test other code? Who will guard the guards?

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard and fast rule on how do you write the scenarios, there isn't any standard format in gherkin either. But, `gherkin` is specifically, for having and making non-technical like BA's, stackholders, non technical managers understand, what the test is really about. The more precise you use the sentences, the more understandable and meaningful it is.

If you are not going to write the steps in a understandable way, there is no need to implement `gherkin` at all. You may just code it in ruby or Java and let the BA's etc.. understand the code on their own.

In your scenario, Using `When` in the third step, makes more sense than `then`.

- `When` is precisely to describe the key action the user/Program
  performs.
- The purpose of `Then` steps is to observe outcomes.

  ```
  Scenario: Retrieve customer license document
  Given I have a customer with no license
  `When` I retrieve the license document
  Then the license document should not be retrieved
  ```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a scenario like this:

```
Scenario: Retrieve customer license document
  Given I have a customer with no license
  When I retrieve the license document
  Then the license document should not be retrieved
```

BDD is all about communication between the development team and the business. What would the business describe the behaviours of the system to be?

Would they say something more like this?:

```
Scenario: Customer has no license
  Given Carl the Customer has no license
  When Bernadette the Business User attempts to retrieve Carl the Customers licence document
  Then Bernadette the Business User should see no license document for this customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Scenario:  Verify that license document should not be retrieve when customer has no license

Given I have a customer with no license -- Given explains what you have

When I retrieve the license document -- When explains what you trying to do

Then verify that the license document should not be retrieved --- it is the final result of scenario